# fipWinImage access error

Tags: c++, freeimage

Currently I'm using fipWinImage to draw image on screen, my code is written in C++(as following).

```
fipWinImage* m_ClientColorImg;

.....

float width = m_ClientColorImg->getWidth();
```

The initialization of `m_ClientColorImg` is not listed here. Sometimes accessing error would occur when I use `getWidth()` function, but I found that the pointer of this `fipWinImage` object is normal, not `NULL` or any corrupted pointers. Does anyone know how to check the `fipWinImage` object to ensure there is data in it? Or could someone figure out the reason of the error probably?

Comment: What error do you get? What do you mean the "object is normal, not [...] any corrupted pointers"? Does not corrupted mean that it does point to a properly constructed object of `fipWinImage`?

Comment: It seems m_ClientColorImg points to a properly constructed object, but the accessing via getWidth() function is not successful. Have you ever met this kind of error?

Comment: Show us how you initialize `m_ClientColorImg`. By the way, it's good practice to initialize pointers at declaration, e.g. `fipWinImage * m_ClientColorImg = NULL` or `nullptr` in C++11

Comment: I put two CPictureControl tools into one CDialog, each binds with a fipWinImage object. In the construction function of the Dialog, I use the same expression as you list to initialize them. These two fipwinImage objects would be filled with data separately and call refresh function to redraw. Before that, it will call clear function  e.g. m_ClientColorImg->clear() to clear data. So I guess when one of the fipWinImage objects call refresh function and redraw, the other one maybe call clear function at the same time. Then the accessing error occurs. @nijansen